# SKNode follow another SKNode within SKConstraint bounds

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am attempting to simulate an eye with SpriteKit.

The pupil of the eye tracks the users's finger as it moves across the screen, but must stay within the bounds of the eye.

I have attempted to solve this unsuccessfully with the use of SKConstraint.

**Edit**

My thought was to apply SKConstraints against the pupil to restrict its bounds to the eye. Any touches (i.e. touchesMoved(), etc) will be applied to the pupil in the form of of SKAction.moveTo() and **SpriteKit handles maintaining the pupil within the eye bound.**

```
let touchPoint = CGPoint()
SKAction.moveTo( touchPoint, duration: 2)
```

The code for the video is available: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2356e07d1ac0e67c25b1940662d72cb

[image: Eyeball video demo]

A picture is worth a thousand words...

Imagine the pupil is the small, white, filled circle. The blue box simulates a user moving their finger across the screen.

Ideally, the pupil follows the blue box around the screen and follows the path as defined by the yellow circle.

iOS 10 | Swift 3 | Xcode 8

Comment: You never write any code to move the pupil,  it looks like it is doing what you want

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Correct. I've edited the answer slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: actually post the code where you are doing this at,  this still is not helpful

Comment: also, you do not want to do a moveTo action, because things can get really complicated.  You could have multiple actions fighting each other.  Instead just move the node to your touch position,  the constraint should move it back.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of constraining by distance, you can use an orientation constraint to rotate a node to face toward the touch location. By adding the "pupil" node with an `x` offset to the node being constrained, the pupil will move toward the touch point. Here's an example of how to do that:

```
let follow = SKSpriteNode(color:.blue, size:CGSize(width:10,height:10))
let pupil = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
let container = SKNode()
let maxDistance:CGFloat = 25

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(container)
    // Add the pupil at an offset
    pupil.position = CGPoint(x: maxDistance, y: 0)
    container.addChild(pupil)

    // Node that shows the touch point
    addChild(follow)

    // Add an orientation constraint to the container
    let range = SKRange(constantValue: 0)        
    let constraint = SKConstraint.orient(to: follow, offset: range)
    container.constraints = [constraint]
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        let location = t.location(in: self)
        follow.position = location
        adjustPupil(location: location)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for t in touches {
        let location = t.location(in: self)
        follow.position = location
        adjustPupil(location: location)
    }
 }

// Adjust the position of the pupil within the iris
func adjustPupil(location:CGPoint) {
    let dx = location.x - container.position.x
    let dy = location.y - container.position.y
    let distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    let x = min(distance, maxDistance)
    pupil.position = CGPoint(x:x, y:0)
}
```

[image]

Comment: This would mean the pupil could never go into the center of the eye,  Just an FYI for OP

Comment: at this point you may as well just go back to the distance constraint, since this is what you are doing anyway lol

Comment: I am simply adjusting the distance of the pupil away from the center. How is this the same as implementing a distance constraint?

Comment: And how do you implement a distance constraint without 1) using an `SKAction` (see your comment above) or 1) adding code to the update method?

Comment: Between the rotating and calculating the inner distance, you have the distance constraint.  (Technically you are just manually doing the distance constraint and rotating the entire eyeball)  What the OP has created already handles this, his only problem is he never updates the pupils location from what I can tell.  As for your second question, you do neither the `SKAction` nor the update, you do it during the `touchesMoved` method

Comment: You didn't answer my second question. How?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking here, you do not calculate the distance every time, the constraint does this for you,  All you have to do is move the pupil to where you are touching, and the distance constraint handles the rest

Comment: How do you move the pupil without adding code to the update?

Comment: you move the pupil in the touchesMoved method

Comment: How do you move the pupil?

Comment: pupil.position = convert blah blah touchedPoint

Comment: I am well aware how constraints work, I do not think you understand how constraints work,  When you move a node outside of said distance, it pushes the node back along the line cast till it is at said distance

Comment: `Each time when constraints are applied, a line is projected between the node’s position and the target node’s position. The distance between the two points is calculated, and if it lies outside the specified range, the node is pushed or pulled along this line until it lies within the range.`  Right from apple docs

Comment: 0x, which website / program did you use to make the GIF? I've been looking for something easy / lightweight to put in my own answers.

Comment: @Fluidity Quicktime to screen capture,  then I just use online sites to convert mov to png

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to wait for a response before I posted an answer, but @0x141E and I debated about how constraints work, so here is the code.  Use it to find out where you are going wrong.

```
import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {
    static let pupilRadius : CGFloat = 30
    static let eyeRadius : CGFloat = 100

    let follow = SKSpriteNode(color:.blue, size:CGSize(width:10,height:10))
    let pupil = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: pupilRadius)

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let eye = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: GameScene.eyeRadius)
        eye.strokeColor = .white
        eye.fillColor = .white
        addChild(eye)

        pupil.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        pupil.fillColor = .blue
        eye.addChild(pupil)

        addChild(follow)

        pupil.constraints = [SKConstraint.distance(SKRange(lowerLimit: 0, upperLimit: GameScene.eyeRadius-GameScene.pupilRadius), to: eye)]

    }

    func moveFollowerAndPupil(_ location:CGPoint){
        follow.position = location
        pupil.position = convert(location, to: pupil.parent!)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach({moveFollowerAndPupil($0.location(in: self))})
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        touches.forEach({moveFollowerAndPupil($0.location(in: self))})
    }
}
```

As you can see, no use of square root on my end, hopefully Apple is smart enough to not use it either since it is not needed, meaning this should in theory be faster than manually doing the distance formula.

[image]

Comment: I thought you were going to move the pupil smoothly from point A to B instead of jumping there in a single step.

Comment: who said anything about that

Comment: The OP was planning to use a `moveTo` action

Comment: Already told OP I would not recommend it, it is a pain in the ass depending on what result he wants to achieve

Comment: Ironically, the `convert` method is more than 20 times slower than `sqrt`. lol

Comment: @0x141E. it is not ironic, technically your method should be using a form of convert also, how are you going to handle when eyeball is a child of face

Comment: LOL come on people, if you are going to down vote politely explain why.  The OP has not provided enough info to solve his problem, this code is to only show 0x141E how to correctly do the distance constraint.  Once the OP explains where his code is missing (which I believe has to do with him not moving his pupil) I can provide a correct answer